# C++ implementation of convolution of 2 independent gamma distributions

Tags: c++, boost, statistics, distribution, gamma

**I need to combine 2 gamma variates with different shape/scale params, which boils down to calculating new shape/scale params.**

I am using boost/std facilities for dealing with statistical problems, and wish to stay there (i.e. avoid doing complicated math computations).

There is a method by P.G. Moschopoulos from 1984 that does that, but I wasn't able to find any c++ code that implements it (let alone doing it by boost/std means), which is quite surprising giving relevance to many engineering problems - e.g. simulating network traffic

Any hints/pointers will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "combine"? Sum of RVs? Product of RVs? Could you provide link to  P.G. Moschopoulos paper?

Comment: I mean - given prob. of events x and y described by gamma variates X and Y, what would be scale and shape of variate Z describing event (x+y) .
Link:
http://www.math.utep.edu/Faculty/moschopoulos/Publications/1985-The_Distribution_of_the_Sum_of_Independent_Gamma_Random_Variables.pdf

Thanks

Comment: Well, after quick search there is an R package done in C++ which implements this method (as well as few other). Interface might be a bit ugly (it has to connect to R), but C++ code looks ok. https://github.com/ChaoranHu/coga, paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.04059.pdf

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, looked at the code, unfortunately there is no way i can extract the calculation of new scale parameter without messing up
Thanks a lot for your comments